# jQuery Show/Hide doing something strange, hiding wrong element

Tags: jquery, image, hover, hide, show

So, I've written a snippet of jQuery that makes sense to me, but it's doing something that I had not intended it to do. On a navigation bar, on rollover, I want a little image to appear underneath using the show/hide functions. So, when I hover over "Home", for example, I want my image.png to appear beneath it. Here's the jQuery.

```
$("#home").hover(
function () {
$(this).show(".mustache_one");
},
function () {
$(this).hide(".mustache_one");
}
);
```

Now what it's doing is when on hover, nothing, and then when removing the mouse from "Home", moving the entire div that contains the navbar to the left to hide the "Home" link. Meanwhile, the image.png never shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the element id/class to `show` or `hide`. Besides, `$this` will refer to `#home`, hence it'll try to show/hide the home element. I don't know your markup, but this is how your JS should look.

```
$("#home").hover(
    function () {
        $('.mustache_one').show('slow');
    },
    function () {
        $('.mustache_one').hide('slow');
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, still getting used to writing things other than HTML and CSS, just need to learn the syntax better. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .show() is performed  on the object(s) you want to perform .show on, e.g. $`(".mustache_one").show();` Same goes for .hide();

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Let me know if this helps, or if you have any questions :)

Comment: `show` does take parameters! The speed and the callback to run after the transition is complete.

Comment: Thank you sir, like I said to Mr. Gangurde, just need to learn the syntax ha.